# Linear transformation? Image?

Tags: matrices

> Consider the space of functions $F=\operatorname{span}\lbrace \sin(x),\cos(x),x\cdot \sin(x), x\cdot \cos(x)\rbrace$ and the image $L:F\rightarrow F:f\rightarrow -f''-2f$.
>
> 1. Show that $L$ is a linear image.
> 2. Find the matrix $M$ of the linear images from $F$ to $F$ with respect to basis $B=\lbrace \sin(x),\cos(x),x\cdot \sin(x), x\cdot \cos(x)\rbrace$.
> 3. What are the eigenvalues of $L$ (and also $M$).
> 4. Give the eigenvectors of $M$ and $L$.
> 5. What is the dimension of the eigenspace?

my attempt:

1. The image is linear because the image of $0$ is $0$?
2. $$\left(\begin{matrix}-\sin(x)\\ -\cos(x)\\ -x\cdot \sin(x)-2\cdot \cos(x)\\ 2\cdot \sin(x)-x\cdot \cos(x)\end{matrix}\right)=\sin(x)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}-1\\ 0\\0\\2\end{matrix}\right)+\cos(x)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ -1\\-2\\0\end{matrix}\right)+x\cdot \sin(x)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\-1\\0\end{matrix}\right) +x \cdot \cos(x)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\0\\-1\end{matrix}\right)$$
   So $M=\left(\begin{matrix}-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -2 & -1 & 0\\ 2 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{matrix}\right)$
3. eigenvalues: $-1, -1, -1, -1$
4. eigenvectors: $\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)$,$\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\0\\-1\end{matrix}\right)$,$\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right)$,$\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right)$
5. dimension eigenspace: $4$?

Comment: Some of what you have done is clearly wrong. A list of eigenvectors ought to be a linearly independent set, but your first and second eigenvectors are not linearly independent, neither are your third and fourth. Also, if those are the only eigenvectors, then (because of the linear dependence) the dimension of the eigenspace is 2, not 4.

Comment: matlab gave me this: A =

    -1     0     0     0
     0    -1     0     0
     0    -2    -1     0
     2     0     0    -1

>> [V,D] = eig(A)

V =

         0    0.0000         0         0
         0         0         0    0.0000
         0         0    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000   -1.0000         0         0


D =

    -1     0     0     0
     0    -1     0     0
     0     0    -1     0
     0     0     0    -1

Comment: Matlab? I thought you said this was *your* attempt. So, what is your real question? Do you understand my comments?

Comment: Yes, just entered the M matrix in matlab to see the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I understand the eigenvectors i wrote are not linearly independent.

Comment: $L(0) = 0$ would tell you that $L$ is injective IF you already knew that $L$ was linear. To show that $L$ is linear, you want to show that $L(f+g) = L(f) + L(g)$.

Comment: As you understand they are not linearly independent, do you understand the dimension is not 4?

Comment: The eigenvalues are -1,-1,-1,-1 because they are the diagonal entries. I find two eigenvectors (0,0,0,1)^T and (0,0,1,0)^T. Is that correct?

Comment: So the eigenspace consists of all the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvectors, which is 2?

Comment: I haven't checked to see whether $M$ is right, but, if it is, then your eigenvectors are now correct. The eigenspace is not 2; the eigenspace is a vector space, whereas 2 is a number. But the *dimension* of the eigenspace is 2.